How do I fix the home page rendering in this pkgdown + GitLab workflow?
I'm having issues with the pkgdown homepage for an R package I created.
When I build_site() from my PC, the site created in my local directory looks as I expect.  It is using the REAMDE.md file that I created by knitting README.Rmd as the homepage.
But when I build the site on GitLab in a CI/CD pipeline, it seems to instead build a very minimal home page based on my DESCRIPTION file.  There is just one like of text with the package description and no content from README.  (The function documentation seems fine).
It's pretty hard to make a reproducible example for a GitLab CI/CD pipeline, unfortunately.
Here is my pipeline script:
image: rocker/tidyverse

stages:          # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

build-job:       # This job runs in the build stage, which runs first.
  tags:
    - [runner name]
  stage: build
  script:
    - /bin/bash 
    - echo "no build"

unit-test-job:   # This job runs in the test stage.
  tags:
    - [runner name]
  stage: test    # It only starts when the job in the build stage completes successfully.
  script:
    - /bin/bash
    - echo "no unit tests"

pages:      # This job runs in the deploy stage.
  tags:
    - docker
  stage: deploy  # It only runs when *both* jobs in the test stage complete successfully.
  environment: production
  script:
    - R -e 'install.packages(c("devtools", "pkgdown"))'
    - R -e 'devtools::install()'
    - R -e 'pkgdown::build_site()'
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public

This text from the R packages 2e textbook seem relevant, but I admit I don't fully understand.

Home page
The main content of the home page (index.html) is generated
from pkgdown/index.md, index.md, or README.md, in that order. Most
packages will use README.md because that's also displayed by GitHub
and CRAN. Use index.md if you want your package website to look
different to your README, and use pkgdown/index.md if you don't want
that file to live in your package root directory.
If you use index.Rmd or README.Rmd it's your responsibility to knit
the document to create the corresponding .md. pkgdown does not do this
for you because it only touches files in the doc/ directory.


It took a while, but I found the issue.  My remote repo had a "readme.md" in it and although my local repo had "README.md", git would not push a separate file.
pkgdown expects "README.md" in caps, so the "readme.md" was not selected as the home page.
